# Duda sobre la carga de scripts con elementos dinamicos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en esto de javascript y tengo una duda; no sé si el título esta bien planteado.

Tengo un sitio con varios *scripts* para que se ejecuten una vez terminada la carga del DOM:

```
function carga_scroll(){
  //Contenido
}
if (document.addEventListener){
   window.addEventListener('load',carga_scroll,false);
} else {
   window.attachEvent('onload',carga_scroll);    
}
```

Esta sintaxis la tengo en varios script. Bueno mi duda viene en que si es correcto usar con elementos que añado dinámicamente las funciones. Por ejemplo este script lo uso para cargar imágenes a medida que el usuario hace scroll entonces justo después de añadir imágenes mediante JS hago una llamada.

```
carga_scroll();
```

Mi pregunta es si es una manera correcta de hacerlo o existe otra forma mas adecuada.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Existen formas más avanzadas. Por ejemplo, usando [dynamic import](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import), lo cual te permite cargar módulos bajo demanda. Pero para esto deberás estar familiarizado con un stack moderno de desarrollo: Babel, Webpack/Rollup, ES6+.

Comment: No pude poner un ejemplo verificable porque utilizo un framework llamado inview. @gugadev No queria complicarme mucho la vida he escuchado hablar de Babel pero para el caso no creo que me compense iniciarme para solucionar este problema. El caso es que según llamo a carga_scroll() vuelve a ejecutar el script perfectamente pero claro no se si eso afecta al rendimiento o simplemente esta mal hecho

Answer (score 1):

Una buena opción, si recién estás arrancando con javascript, es usar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) y utilizar el método de [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler) para ejecutar cualquier función que quieras una vez que termine de renderizar el sitio. Por ejemplo:

```js
// esto se va a ejecutar una vez que termine la carga del DOM
$(document).ready(function() {
  // acá va todo código que quieras hacer una vez que termine
  // de cargar el DOM, tené en cuenta que debería ir todo por dentro
  alert('DOM finish');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Usando sólo javascript:

Si realmente querés hacerlo pero sin jQuery, esta es una opción que suelo utilizar.

#### Usando la estructura de html e inicializandolo al final

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Acá va todo el html -->

<!-- Por debajo de todo el sitio inserto todos los scripts -->
<script>
// función a ejecutar
(function() {
   // cualquier cosa que quieras hacer
   alert('DOM finish');
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Esta es la versión pura de javascript:

Sacado de [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/8968285)

```
(function(funcName, baseObj) {
    // El nombre de la función pública se establece de forma predeterminada en
    // window.docReady, pero puede pasar su propio objeto y su propio nombre de
    // la función, que se utilizarán si desea colocarlos en un espacio de
    // nombres diferente
    funcName = funcName || "docReady";
    baseObj = baseObj || window;
    var readyList = [];
    var readyFired = false;
    var readyEventHandlersInstalled = false;

    // Llamar cuando el documento está listo
    // Esta función se protege de ser llamada más de una vez
    function ready() {
        if (!readyFired) {
            // esto debe establecerse en verdadero antes de que empecemos a llamar
            // devoluciones de llamada
            readyFired = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < readyList.length; i++) {
                // Si aquí ocurre una devolución de llamada para agregar nuevos
                // manejadores listos, la función docReady() verá que ya se activó
                // y programará la devolución de llamada para que se ejecute
                // justo después de que este bucle de eventos finalice, por lo
                // que todos los manejadores seguirán ejecutándose en orden y no
                // se agregarán nuevos a la lista mientras la procesamos
                readyList[i].fn.call(window, readyList[i].ctx);
            }
            // Permitir cualquier cierre mantenido por estas funciones para liberar
            readyList = [];
        }
    }

    function readyStateChange() {
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            ready();
        }
    }

    // Esta es la única interfaz pública docReady (fn, context);
    // el argumento de contexto es opcional; si está presente, se pasará como un
    // argumento a la devolución de llamada
    baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
        if (typeof callback !== "function") {
            throw new TypeError("callback for docReady(fn) must be a function");
        }
        // si ya está listo, entonces solo programe la devolución de llamada
        // para que se dispare de forma asíncrona, pero de inmediato
        if (readyFired) {
            setTimeout(function() {callback(context);}, 1);
            return;
        } else {
            // agrega la función y el contexto a la lista
            readyList.push({fn: callback, ctx: context});
        }
        // Si el documento ya está listo para funcionar, programe la función ready
        // para ejecutarse
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            setTimeout(ready, 1);
        } else if (!readyEventHandlersInstalled) {
            // de lo contrario, si no tenemos instalados controladores de
            // eventos, instálelos
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                // La primera opción es el event DOMContentLoaded
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, false);
                // Por si no funciona window load event
                window.addEventListener("load", ready, false);
            } else {
                // Debe ser IE
                document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", readyStateChange);
                window.attachEvent("onload", ready);
            }
            readyEventHandlersInstalled = true;
        }
    }
})("docReady", window);
```

#### Uso:

```
// pasa una función como referencia
docReady(fn);

// usa una función anónima
docReady(function() {
    // code here
});

// pasa una función como referencia y un contexto
// the context will be passed to the function as the first argument
docReady(fn, context);

// usa una función anónima con un contexto
docReady(function(context) {
    // code here
}, ctx);
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. LLevo años usando Jquery pero queria hacer mi aplicación lo mas ligera posible. Además asi aprobecho para iniciarme y profundizar un poco en javascript puro. Creo que es mala practica iniciarse en jQuery como hice yo sin saber previamente javascript. Un saludo

Comment: @pablo ahí te agregué la respuesta con la versión pura de javascript.