# Duda sobre rendimiento al usar getElementsByClassName y onClick()

Tags: javascript

Recientemente me ha surgido una duda. En javascript al usar onclick() y getElementsByClassName se requiere hacer un bucle para recorrer todos los elementos. Mi pregunta es si se realiza esto bastantes veces ¿Puede afectar al rendimiento? ¿existe otra alternativa?. Gracias

```js
ahref=document.getElementsByClassName('btnClick');
for (var i=0; i < ahref.length; i++) {
    ahref[i].onclick = function(){
        alert('hola');
    }
};
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClick">Click1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClick">Click2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClick">Click3</a>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para casos como el que planteas, donde quieres establecer un mismo *event handler* para múltiples elementos del DOM se suele utilizar una técnica llamada **event delegation**.

Tiene menos impacto sobre el rendimiento, además de una sintaxis mucho más simple.

Puedes leer más sobre ella aquí https://javascript.info/event-delegation

En pocas palabras, consiste en vincular el *event listener* al elemento padre que contenga todos los elementos que quieres trackear, en lugar de vincularlo a los propios elementos.
Como elemento padre comodín también puedes usar *document*, ya que es el elemento del que desciende todo.

Después, se usan condicionales para aplicar los *event handlers* solo a los elementos que te interesen, filtrando por cualquier condición: clase, id, tag...

Puedes usar tantas condicionales como quieras dentro de cada *event listener*.

El ejemplo que adjuntas quedaría así usando event delegation:

```
document.onclick = event => {
  if (event.target.matches('.btnClick')) {
    alert('hola');
  }
};
```

---

**EDICIÓN**: En respuesta al segundo comentario.

Si hubiera varios elementos .div_padre y quisieras vincular el *event handler* SOLO a los elementos .btnClick hijos de algún .div_padre:

```
document.onclick = event => {
  if (event.target.matches('.div_padre .btnClick')) {
    alert('hola');
  }
};
```

Tanto `element.querySelector('selector-css')` como `element.matches('selector-css')` aceptan cualquier selector de css válido, tan complejo como quieras.

Comment: vaya despues de mucho buscar es la primera solucion que encuentro sin recurrir a bucles, sera la solucion que usan softwares tipo jquery. Y esto funciona cuando añades elementos dinámicos? es uno de los problemas que tengo con mi sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267469/duda-sobre-la-carga-de-scripts-con-elementos-dinamicos-en-javascript Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Estube realizando pruebas y si en el ejemplo que comentaba los a href tuviera un div padre cuya clase  fuera .div_padre prodria hacer algo asi:document.getElementsByClassName('div_padre ').onclick = function(e){.... pero si hubiera varios div llamados div_padre  tendria que usar un bucle o directamente como lo has puesto en el ejemplo ¿verdad? Gracias

Comment: Buenas Pablo, te respondo a tu primer comentario: event delegation funciona perfectamente con elementos _child_ dinámicos, de hecho es una de sus ventajas. En el ejemplo de arriba si más tarde se crearan más elementos con la clase .btnClick se les aplicaría el _event handler_ automáticamente.

Comment: Sobre el segundo comentario:

Comment: Tendrías que usar _document.querySelector('.div_padre').onclick_ para seleccionar solamente el primer elemento con la clase .div_padre, entendiendo que solo hay uno. También podrías usar una id en lugar de una clase si lo ves más claro. En caso de que hubiera varios elementos .div_padre te actualizo mi respuesta con el código que podrías usar.

Comment: En el segundo ejemplo que colocaste ya lo hice en mi script. El problema por asi decirlo es que de esa forma tendria que escribir document.onclick = event => {.... en varios script que tengo en mi sitio y no se si me afectara al rendimiento. Mi idea en un principio er usar  document.getElementsByClassName('div_padre ').onclick = function(e){.... pero veo que si hay mas de un div_padre no hay otra opcion que la que has comentado

Comment: Esa idea que comentas, usando _document.getElementsByClassName('div_padre ').onclick_ (si funcionara) te aseguro que sería menos eficiente que ponerle el listener al document entero, ya que en realidad lo que haría es iterar sobre todos los elementos _.div_padre_ y ponerle un event listener a cada uno. Aunque sea contraintuitivo, ponerle el listener directamente a document (o a otro elemento que contenga a todos los elementos .div_padre), aunque sea varias veces, es mucho más eficiente que iterar varias veces sobre ciertos elementos y ponerle un listener a cada uno.

Comment: y si utilizo addEventListener podria repetirlo en varios documentos de mi pagina sin afectar al rendimiento?. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Sí, _document.addEventListener(click, myFunction)_ es sinónimo de _document.onlick = myFunction_, si te refieres a eso. Event delegation es el método más eficiente en cuanto a rendimiento, pero eso no quita que lo mejor sea concentrar los event handlers vinculados al mismo elemento padre bajo el mismo event listener. Es decir, cuantos menos document.addEventListener(mismoEvento, myFunction), mejor.

Comment: Vale voy a marcar la pregunta como resuelta muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Solo tengo una pregunta mas que no di conseguido informacion al respecto. Con scroll, resize y orientationchange se puede crear delegacion de eventos?

Comment: Perdona por tardar tanto en contestar, la verdad es que no sé la respuesta a tu pregunta, aunque supongo que sí se puede usar. Lo que sí te puedo decir es que los event listener de ese tipo de eventos que mencionas afectan mucho al rendimiento, ya que son eventos que se producen continuamente pueden llegar a dispararse varias veces por segundo. Para evitar esto en parte puedes buscar información de una técnica llamada _debouncing_. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Más allá del estilo que tenga cada uno para iterar:

Añadir un eventListener (es lo que estás haciendo por detrás) a un lote de elementos siempre tendrás que hacerlo iterando sobre la colección de elementos.

```
ahref.forEach(el => { 
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert('hola')
    })
}));
```

La otra opción que tienes es añadir a cada elemento `a` la propiedad `onclick` en lugar de hacerlo programáticamente.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClick" onclick="alert('hola')">Click1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClick" onclick="alert('hola')">Click2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClick" onclick="alert('hola')">Click3</a>
```

Una opción que tienes para no estar constantemente declarando las funciones anónimas para cada elemento es usar siempre la misma función nombrada fuera del bucle, por ejemplo:

```
function sayHi {
  alert('hola');
}
```

y en tu `onclick` en lugar de poner tu funcion anónima poner `sayHi()` o en el callback de tu eventListener de `click`.

Comment: el problema que tengo con los bucles es el tema del rendimiento. Probe varias soluciones pero no me terminan de convencer para esto.